# The completion of the ring of Laurent polynomials with respect to the augmentation ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, formal-completions

Let $A = \langle a\rangle$ be an infinite cyclic group on one generator. I'm trying to understand the completion $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}}A$ of the group algebra $\mathbb{Q}A$ with respect to the augmentation ideal $I = \ker(a \mapsto 1)$.

Can someone give an explicit (or just helpful) description of this ring?

One direction I have looked at is the following.  The group ring $\mathbb{Q}A$ is the ring of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb{Q}[a,a^{-1}]$ and the ideal $I$ is generated by $1-a$ and $1-a^{-1}$. So perhaps the completion $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}[a,a^{-1}]}$ with respect to powers of $I$, is some sort of ring of power series in variables $1-a$ and $1-a^{-1}$...

Ideally I hope to understand the coalgebra structure of $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}}A$ as well, in particular I'd like to determine the Lie algebra of primitive elements (when viewing $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}}A$ as a complete Hopf algebra).

Comment: Note that $\langle a\rangle$ is proper usage and $<a>$ is not. I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[a,a^{-1}]$ is a pid and $1-a$ generates a prime ideal. (Note that $1-a^{-1}=-a^{-1}(1-a)$). So, the completion is just isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$.

Comment: @Mohan ah yes I didn't spot that simplification. Are you using some commutative algebra fact about completions of pid's w.r.t. prime ideals?